# Working with Object with dynamically assigned keys and value as an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

How to pull or push "sessionId" inside of Object with dynamically assigned keys and value as an arrays such nested models in MongoDB?

```
   {"_id": {"5e018a5ab887078c3cffca69"}, "items":. 
   [{"id":"BOX191219105528111","sessions":{"session1":. 
   [{"sessionId": "1A"}, {"sessionId": "2A"}], "session2": 
   [{"sessionId": "12D"}, {"sessionId": "1D"}] `
```

Comment: Please tell what add key ??

Comment: here they are: "session1" and "session2". And so on. I have them as a variables, like `x="session1", y = "session2"` So I would like to pass this variables to find method and try to make pull or push request.

Comment: burkhantiinod@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I have used aggregation framework:

`{$project: sessions: {$objectToArray: "$sessions"}}`

After that we got array to work easier with.